# Platform for an Image eCommerce site?

Tags: e-commerce, photo-gallery

Have looked at ImageFolio but it doesn't seem to be a complete match for what the client wants to achieve. At this photo ecommerce site:

1. Member users upload and tag photos.
2. Photos are reviewed by admins before going live.
3. Buyers to purchase credits.
4. Buyers use credits to download photos (instead of a shopping cart process)
5. Buyers can toggle an option to not see photos they have already purchased.
6. Backend tracks sales per member user for later compensation.

Also, in several of the examples ImageFolio lists of sites using their software, either the site isn't working, or [script errors](http://www.awestock.com/cgi-bin/e-store/imageFolio.cgi?img=0&cat=all&bool=or&search=stones&x=0&y=0) are thrown, or they don't look very nice... Should this trouble me?

Answer (score 0):

You'd be smart to avoid ImageFolio like the plague. It's awful, outdated, and the company simply doesn't provide support. It was one of the better solutions back in the day, but there are much better OSS solutions out there. Just google "Digital Asset Management" and take your pick.

I'm saying this because I'm currently looking for a way to move a client away from ImageFolio -- that's how I found your question.